# Android studio Virtualization (Intel HAXM)

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to run the emulator in the android studio (in the AVD Manager).

But i get this error :

[image: Intel HAXM Problem]

I enabled the Virtualization in my BIOS :

[image: BIOS Settings]

What can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Two possibilities :

1. Sometimes your Antivirus may block the Virtualization settings.
   Disable your Antivirus and Try installing HAXM
2. Disable Hyper-V :

> Control Panel -> "Programs" -> "Turn Windows features on or off"
>   (under "Programs and Features") and locate "Hyper-V", uncheck, reboot.